# Get list of related tracks HTTP API SoundCloud

Tags: soundcloud

I wasn't able to find anything fitting in HTTP API documentation.
As I know, there's some tracks popping out in SC widget after current track is finished, therefore there is some related tracks functionality in SC itself, yet can we access it via API?
I.e get a list of tracks, related to given track's id.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Disclaimer: This is an undocumented endpoint and is subject to change at anytime by SoundCloud.**

There is an undocumented endpoint that allows you to access a track's related sounds:

```
HTTP GET: https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/[TRACK_ID]/related?client_id=[YOUR_CLIENT_ID]
```

You didn't specify a language, so i'm just going to give a high-level overview on how to use the endpoint.

First, get your track URL.  I'll use this one as an example:  https://soundcloud.com/msmrsounds/ms-mr-hurricane-chvrches-remix

Then hit the `resolve` endpoint to get the track_id.

```
HTTP GET: https://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsoundcloud.com%2Fmsmrsounds%2Fms-mr-hurricane-chvrches-remix&client_id=[YOUR_CLIENT_ID]
```

Response:

```
{
  "status": "302 - Found",
  "location": "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/90787841.json?client_id=[YOUR_CLIENT_ID]"
}
```

Next, hit the `related` endpoint with your `track_id`.

```
HTTP GET: https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/90787841/related?client_id=[YOUR_ClIENT_ID]
```

The full response will give you up to 50 related tracks.  The response is too large to post, but it's just an array of tracks.

```
[
  {
    "kind": "track",
    "id": 112741336,
    "created_at": "2013/09/27 09:40:29 +0000",
    "user_id": 59817646,
    "duration": 215896,
    "commentable": true,
    "state": "finished",
    "original_content_size": 38068298,
    "last_modified": "2015/04/04 20:17:24 +0000",
    "sharing": "public",
    "tag_list": "CHVRCHES Whitney Houston Zane Lowe",
    "permalink": "chvrches-its-not-right-but-its",
    "streamable": true,
    "embeddable_by": "all",
    "downloadable": false,
    "purchase_url": null,
    "label_id": null,
    "purchase_title": null,
    "genre": "Electronic",
    "title": "CHVRCHES - It's Not Right But It's Okay (Whitney Houston Cover)",
    "description": "CHVRCHES - It's Not Right But It's OK (Whitney Houston Cover) from Zane's Live Sessions",
    "label_name": "",
    "release": "",
    "track_type": "recording",
    "key_signature": "",
    "isrc": "",
    "video_url": null,
    "bpm": null,
    "release_year": null,
    "release_month": null,
    "release_day": null,
    "original_format": "wav",
    "license": "all-rights-reserved",
    "uri": "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/112741336",
    "user": {
      "id": 59817646,
      "kind": "user",
      "permalink": "uknewmusic",
      "username": "UKNewMusic",
      "last_modified": "2013/09/27 09:38:04 +0000",
      "uri": "https://api.soundcloud.com/users/59817646",
      "permalink_url": "http://soundcloud.com/uknewmusic",
      "avatar_url": "https://a1.sndcdn.com/images/default_avatar_large.png"
    },
    "permalink_url": "http://soundcloud.com/uknewmusic/chvrches-its-not-right-but-its",
    "artwork_url": "https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000058757165-6tnuep-large.jpg",
    "waveform_url": "https://w1.sndcdn.com/XkEffI5hwjZ7_m.png",
    "stream_url": "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/112741336/stream",
    "playback_count": 680326,
    "download_count": 0,
    "favoritings_count": 9241,
    "comment_count": 199,
    "attachments_uri": "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/112741336/attachments",
    "policy": "ALLOW"
  },
  { ...
  }
]
```

Comment: I did not specify language, becouse I was honestly expecting quick and lazy answer (which is perfectly fine). Language is JavaScript and I am already using route url->resolve->something else in my code, therefore, knowing this endpoint, rest must be pretty easy for me. Thx. I'm wondering why is it undocumented, don't you know?

Comment: @MaxYari Not sure exactly why this isn't exposed, there could be a multitude of reasons known only to the internal staff at SoundCloud.

Comment: yeah thx again, not tested this yet, but i see no reason why it wouldnt work, marked