# "SoundCloud search suggest" via public SoundCloud API?

Tags: soundcloud

Is there a way to get results like api-v2 SoundCloud search suggest via public SoundCloud API? Also where will the api-v2 be available for 3rd party application use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get list of related tracks HTTP API SoundCloud](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29459145/get-list-of-related-tracks-http-api-soundcloud)

Comment: Thanks. This will solve my other question.  I discovered that a could search for tracks and users and present results in form like 'suggest' does.   So my issue resolved. But what about api-v2 availability?

Comment: @hexlotar do you mean that you want to integrate auto-complete function for you app?